# How to add number of div's in DOM based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I created a simple form**, where user can only type in numbers. And when they do, a number of div's(boxes) should show in the browser, based on the number the user types in to the input field.

It's all done in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anderslund007/pen/LWobqW?editors=1010).

**This is my HTML.**

```
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700" 
  rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

   <!--_-_-_-_INPUT_FIELD_-_-_-_-->
   <div class="input-container">
    <form id="inputForm">
     <input type="number" id="input-box" name="quantity" min="1" max="">
     <input id="filldetails" name="submit" type="submit" value="Add 
       boxes">
    </form>
   </div>

  <!--_-_-_-_BOX-Container_-_-_-_-->
  <div class="boxes-container">
    <div id="boxes"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

**THIS IS MY JS**

```
const form = document.getElementById('inputForm');
const input = inputForm.querySelector('input');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const boxInput = input.value;
  console.log(input.value);
});
```

I get the submit form to respond to the console, so I know its working.

**My question(s) are:**

How do I get the user input to create a as many divs in the DOM as the user wants to?

Do I use a for loop to iterate through the div as many times as the user has put in, in the input field? If so, what is best practice?

I would also like when the user opens the page, that there are zero div's visible and when the add a number, the div's show, if that makes any sense?

Thanks :)

Comment: in jquery or javascript?

Comment: I want to do it in javascript

Comment: You mean plain javascript? it looks like you using Jquery already!

Comment: What have you tried? You need to struggle a little bit rather than asking for an easy answer! That's the way you learned. Try then try harder!

Comment: Yeah im using both, JQuery and JS, I've tried the getElementById, and then appendChild to the boxes-container, but no luck there. Yes I know, I've tried some methods, but also I would like to get some best practices on this aswell.

Comment: take a look at my answer. no jQuery needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look a jQuery's [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

create class called `.hide` and have it set to `.hide { display: none; }`

Add this to the Square element you have in the HTML already.

What you will do then is clone this square `x` amount of times, and remove the `.hide` class for each one.

This can be done like so:

HTML:

```
<form class="boxForm">
    <input type="number" class="boxInput"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<div class="boxContainer">
    <div class="box hide"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

    $('.boxForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var amount = $('.boxInput').val();
        for(i=0; i<amount; i++){
            var newBox = $('.hide').clone();
            newBox.removeClass('hide');
            newBox.appendTo('.boxContainer');
        }
    });

});
```

JSFIDDLE Link working with same code as above:

https://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/3ba9uu9o/

JSFIDDLE Link using `<ul>` element as requested in comments

https://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/3ba9uu9o/4/

Comment: Just pointing out that yes you can achieve this without jQuery and the likes but... just look how little code there is here!

Comment: but you just added a library just for this.

Comment: What Jai said, and pure JS > jQuery for performance. But, concise code has value too. It's a tradeoff and developers could go either way.

Comment: I personally think given the performance of machines in today's age, adding a jQuery library to make your code much more readable for other developers (and yourself) is 100x more valuable then making your code super optimized.

Comment: @Panomosh Thanks, do you know if it is possible or a good idea to store the box divs inside an ul?

Comment: @AndersLund whether it's a good idea or not is completely up to you and what you want to achieve! You would quite easily do this though yes. Just make the object you are cloning a `<li>` element with a `<div class="box">` inside it and append that into a `<ul>` element rather than the `.boxContainer` div

Comment: @AndersLund I have added another version of the JSFIDDLE that is using a `<ul>` for you to have a look at

Comment: @Panomosh Thanks :))

Comment: @Panomosh Okey, so I have one more question for now :) If I were to make the program to always start from scratch. So if I typed in 3, three boxes shows up. And the after that I type in 2, the two boxes shows. Because now it just adds, on top of eachother. How would I do that, can you just give me a hint? so I can solve it myself. Would I have to create a new function under the old one? or what do I have to do? agian, thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the input in the bound event:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('inputForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission
  const input = form.querySelector('input');
  const boxInput = input.value; // get the value
  let box = document.querySelector('#boxes');
    box.innerHTML="";
  for (let i = 0; i < boxInput; i++) { // loop over the input value
    let div = document.createElement('div'); // create div elem
    div.textContent = `Box-${i}`
    box.appendChild(div); // now append in the DOM elem
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <form id="inputForm">
    <input type="number" id="input-box" name="quantity" min="1" max="">
    <input id="filldetails" name="submit" type="submit" value="Add 
       boxes">
  </form>
</div>

<!--_-_-_-_BOX-Container_-_-_-_-->
<div class="boxes-container">
  <div id="boxes"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: const input = inputForm.querySelector('input'); doesn't work

Comment: inputForm isn't defined. Look at your code. It should refer to form. Luckily, you don't use it for appending anyway since you go straight to box, so you won't catch that functionally. But it's wrong.

Comment: Or does using the arrow somehow make form into inputForm...?

Comment: Ah! i get it. that is working because of the id attribute of the form in the global. @JohnVandivier Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on your codepen, no jQuery needed:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('inputForm');

 form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission

  var input = form.querySelector('input');
  var boxInput = input.value;

  for(var i=0; i < boxInput; i++){
     var div = document.createElement('div');
     div.className = 'box';
     document.getElementById('boxes-container').appendChild(div);
  }
});
```

```css
#boxes-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-wrap': 'wrap;
}

.box {
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  
  <!--_-_-_-_INPUT_FIELD_-_-_-_-->
  <div class="input-container">
    <form id="inputForm">
      <input type="number" id="input-box" name="quantity" min="1" max="">
      <input id="filldetails" name="submit" type="submit" value="Add boxes">
    </form>
  </div>
  
  <!--_-_-_-_BOX-Container_-_-_-_-->
  <div id="boxes-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```